# send message from android telegram source to to specific user id

Tags: java, android, telegram

I want to know, how can i send a message (for ex: text) from owner client to some body's id with coding(dynamically)in android telegram source?
what is that method?and objects?
if i want explain more i mean send message (to specific user id )from one of telegram source classes.
here is telegram source [GitHub](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) take look on it(the bad point is, it haven't any comment)

these classes may help to find it, but i cant figure it out

```
MessageObject.java
TLRPC.Message.java
ChatAttachAlert.java
SendMessagesHelper.java
ChatActivity.java
```

thanks.

Comment: Check Messagescontroller.java

Comment: @tashakori have you done it?
give me right method
thanks body

Comment: No, I haven't used this functionality up to now. i checked again and found that it is not in the messagescontroller! you should use something like this method: SendMessagesHelper.getInstance().sendMessage(). note that it's a network call and you should call it in a thread other than ui thread.

Comment: @tashakori i know that method, the problem is about how should i fill method argument params(for ex: MessageObject, peer,etc...)

Comment: simplest way to send a message is like calling: SendMessagesHelper.getInstance().sendMessage("Hi there", 123456789, null, null, false, null, null, null);
...
if you want to find out how to send other types of messages, search the java codes directory for "sendmessageshelper" and find how the sendMessage function is used.

Comment: @tashakori i will try it now "123456789" is to_user id?

Comment: yeah, replace it with the user_id of your own or your friend's

Comment: @tashakori thanks it works :-) 
do you know about MessageObject ? what is that?
body sent your comments as answer then i can accept it

Comment: I dont know what exactly do you want to know about the messsageObject, but as a general info: each message has lots of properties such as owner, date, media, pertaining replymessage, ... . For more information you may refer to https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/MessageObject.java.

Comment: Sure, i will publish the conclusion of the comments as a reply.;-)

Comment: this method not worked for me please help me mr tashakori
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58190948/send-message-to-all-group-and-users-telegram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use something like this method: SendMessagesHelper.getInstance().sendMessage(). note that it's a network call and you should call it in a thread other than ui thread.

simplest way to send a message is like calling:

```
   SendMessagesHelper.getInstance().sendMessage("Hi there", to_user_id, null, null, false, null, null, null);
```

There are different types of messages and different ways to use this function. if you want to find out how to send other types of messages, search the java codes directory for "sendmessageshelper" and find how the sendMessage function is used in them.